# Struggling with Mongoose query operator syntax

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

sorry for the noob question.

I'm trying to write the CRUD endpoints for a Friendship model, which holds two users' IDs.

To create a Friendship the first thing I want to do is check if there is already an instance of that model, which would hold both IDs in any given order, so I wrote:

```
Friendship.findOne.all({users: [user1.id, user2.id]})
  .then(.....
```

But the server responds with a 500 error: `Friendship.findOne.all is not a function`

What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: In short you want to check if both given 2 ids exist in your db or not?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want to check if both `id` `records/documents` are present in your `collection` or not so for that you use `$in` operator like this

```
Friendship.find({id: {$in : [user1.id, user2.id]} })
  .then(.....
```

This will return an `array` of records if any of `id` records will be present. And it will return empty `array` if non of the `id` records will present in your db